# How to create changeset for nested resource w/ Ecto/Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a nested resource in my Phoenix application for which I'm trying to create a changeset. The problem is that `Ecto.build_assoc` expects the map to have atom keys but my params have string keys. What is the proper way to create a changeset for a nested resource?

```
def create(conn, %{"component" => component_params}, generator) do
  changeset = Ecto.build_assoc(generator, :components, component_params) # attributes don't get set
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling your `changeset` function will, if written conventionally, will handle the casting you're looking for using [`Ecto.Changeset.Cast/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4).

Phoenix/Ecto intentionally distrust raw user input. Changesets are the "Ecto way" to handle this.

Here's a more conventional way to handle the operation your going for in your controller:

```
def create(conn, %{"component" => component_params}, generator) do
  changeset =
    generator
    |> Ecto.build_assoc(:components)
    |> Component.changeset(component_params)
  ...
end
```

Given that you have something like this in `component.ex`:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
end
```